# Shows Null while debugging

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, html, null

[image: Null Image]When clicking the button the result is not displayed and while checking through the inspect ==> console, it shows the value as null.

**Apex Class**

```
public class surveycls {
 public static List<Answers__c> AnsList;

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) 
public static List<Survey__c> querySurvey() {
         return[SELECT Name, Id FROM Survey__c];
   }

 @AuraEnabled
   public static List<Question__c> questSurvey(Id SurveyId) {
List<Question__c> qstList = [SELECT Id, Name, Choose_any_of_the_option__c FROM Question__c where Survey__c=:SurveyId];
    set<Id> qstId = New set<Id>();
      for (Question__c qst : qstList) {
          qstId.add(qst.Id);
    }
      AnsList = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Answers__c where Question__c IN : qstId];
     return qstList;
}

@AuraEnabled 
public static List<Answers__c> ansSurvey(){
     return AnsList;
}
}
```

**Javascript**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, } from 'lwc';
import questSurvey from '@salesforce/apex/surveycls.questSurvey';
import ansSurvey from '@salesforce/apex/surveycls.ansSurvey';
export default class surveycls extends LightningElement {

@api questionrecord;
@api surveyrecord;
@track quest;
@track error;
@track ans;

connectedCallback() {
      questSurvey({ SurveyId: this.surveyrecord })
         .then(result => {
             this.quest = result;
             console.log('questions', this.quest);
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 this.error = error;
              })
    

             ansSurvey({ QuestionId: this.questionrecord })
                 .then(result => {
                     this.ans = result;
                     console.log('Answers', this.ans);
              })               
               .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                })
        }
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Question with Choices" icon-name="utility:answer">
        <template if:true={quest}>
           <template for:each={quest} for:item="Question">
               <p key={Question.Id}>{Question.Name}</p>
           </template>
      </template>
      <template if:true={ans}>
         <template for:each={ans} for:item="Answer">
             <p key={Answer.Id}>{Answer.Name}</p>
      </template>
   </template>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because in your `ansSurvey()` method you are assuming the context or class instance will be maintained. LWC methods should be independent units of code which does not really on any context outside the method. You can definitely rely on DB state and Platform cache but not class instances unless you are passing it around.

A way to make your code work is to include the call to `questSurvey` and this would make sure the `ansList` is populated.

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static List<Answers__c> ansSurvey(Id surveyId){
     surveycls.questSurvey(surveyId);
     return AnsList;
}
```

Moving forward, a more concise way of writing this would be.

```
public with sharing class SurveyCls {

    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<Survey__c> querySurvey() {
        return [SELECT Name, Id FROM Survey__c];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Question__c> questSurvey(Id surveyId) {
        return [
                SELECT Id, Name, Choose_any_of_the_option__c
                FROM Question__c
                WHERE Survey__c = :surveyId
        ];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Answers__c> ansSurvey(Id surveyId) {
        return [
                SELECT Id,Name
                FROM Answers__c
                WHERE Question__c IN (
                        SELECT Id, Name, Choose_any_of_the_option__c
                        FROM Question__c
                        WHERE Survey__c = :surveyId
                )
        ];
    }
}
```

This is not executed.

Comment: Hi, @manjit5190. Thanks a lot. I got a question, while changing code as you said above (the first one), the null issue is solved but, it's not displaying the answers. Could you please help me with that?